# javascript freeze columns and rows in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

I have a grid. there is first 4 column static and other are changes according data. i want to fridge first 4 column and scroll other by them. like excel fridge pane

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is "freeze", not "fridge". Perhaps you will have more luck googling for a result now?

Answer (score 0):

i found jQuery plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, it can be apply to GridView

look the website: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Supported Browsers

Internet Explorer 7, 8 (IE 9 Compatibility) Internet Explorer 9
    (9.0.8112) Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 Preview Google
    Chrome(23.0.1271.64 m) Mozilla Firefox (16.0.2) Apple Safari (5.1.7)